How to enable decoding of contract interactions using safe-infrastructure
Hi I've successfully set up the safe-infrastructure repo to support our chain and added the transaction builder app so that I can do contract interactions. I can create contract interactions and approve them just fine but it's not decoding the transactions so I don't know what I'm approving. I've already verified the contract with Sourcify and the ABI loads automatically in the tx builder app.
I have safe apps and contract interactions features enabled for the chain in the config. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Adding more information here, I had to add and use the tx builder app as a custom app in the UI, the tx builder does not show up in the New Transaction flow as it does in the official SAFE web app.

Does this endpoint for decoding data help you? https://docs.safe.global/core-api/transaction-service-reference/mainnet#Data-decoder
